# What is the core functionality of the 'secret' option in express-session?

Tags: node.js, express, web-development-server

I am trying to understand the functionality and relevance of the 'secret' option in express-session.

I have already tried browsing online for some information regarding this, but couldn't find anything substantial.

This is what I found on the npm express-session package page:
secret

Required option

This is the secret used to sign the session ID cookie. This can be either a string for a single secret, or an array of multiple secrets. If an array of secrets is provided, only the first element will be used to sign the session ID cookie, while all the elements will be considered when verifying the signature in requests.

I don't understand how exactly does secret accomplish signing the session ID cookie. How exactly is this required feature implemented behind the scenes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behind the scenes `express-session` is using another module to do the signing `cookie-signature` [link here](https://github.com/tj/node-cookie-signature). It is a very small implementation you can look up.

Essentially you are creating a hash which is set to be the cookie value. That hash in itself is the representation of the data we are setting into the cookie.

If you take a look at the implementation of `express-session`, it uses the cookie name like so:

```
// get the session cookie name
  var name = opts.name || opts.key || 'connect.sid'
```

And sets the cookie via

```
function setcookie(res, name, val, secret, options) {
  var signed = 's:' + signature.sign(val, secret);
  var data = cookie.serialize(name, signed, options);

  debug('set-cookie %s', data);

  var prev = res.getHeader('set-cookie') || [];
  var header = Array.isArray(prev) ? prev.concat(data) : [prev, data];

  res.setHeader('set-cookie', header)
}
```

### But Why?

Sessions can contain sensitive data so the cookie value is securely stored as a hash.

For example:
The session (user) beside authenticating on your server, they have resources on an external Microsoft ActiveDirectory. On login, set the AC username and password (which may differ from your own servers username and password) is set to the cookie and hashed.

**NOTICE**: if data is an `object`, `JSON.stringify(object)`

In this way users can access their AC resources through your server in a secure way. And your development flow gets a lot easier.

```
req.session // {AcUsername: 'myAccUser', AcPass: 'myAccPass'}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: To further elaborate on your answer, I found this [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/87269/how-is-the-session-id-sent-securely) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The `secret` is used to sign [here](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/index.js#L635)